# How to: Android app periodically checks for new content on its own

Tags: android, notifications, updates

So push notifications are needlessly complicated for such a simple thing and I can't find a good enough tutorial for it (I actually need to collect ids for every person who installs my app for it to work?? why is there no "all" option?) so given that my new content is posted at very regular intervals I can just make the app wake up at specific times to download the new content and alert the user... is there a way to do this? It seems like it would be a lot simpler.

I know how to do the code to check for new content, what I need help with is figuring out if there's a way to get the app to wake up on its own and run an asynctask to check for updates if the app is not currently running.

Is this possible?

Comment: Use AlarmManager. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: Or just use a sync adapter http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use Parse Platform for Push Notifications ...which Automatically triggers all the phones which has installed you Application..

Here is tutorial :
[Android Parse Push Notification](https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications)